# Photo library asset's mediaType sometimes is inaccurate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Writing a multiple image picker in Swift here. The steps are as follows:

1. Fetch all assets from photo library
2. Display the thumbnails of them in a `UICollectionView`
3. For those that are videos, put a small label that says "Video" in the bottom right corner of the cell

Here's the code I have:

```
class PhotoLibraryViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    private class PhotoLibraryAsset {
        var assetType: String        // Either "Video" or "Photo"
        var thumbnail: UIImage

        init(assetType: String, thumbnail: UIImage) {
            self.assetType = assetType
            self.thumbnail = thumbnail
        }
    }

    var photos: [PhotoLibraryAsset]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getAllPhotos()
    }

    private func getAllPhotos() {
        // Grab all photos & videos instead of just photos
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor.init(
                key: "creationDate",
                ascending: false
            )
        ]
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate.init(
                format: "mediaType = %d || mediaType = %d",
                PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue,
                PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue
            )
        fetchOptions.fetchLimit = Int.max

        let imageManager = PHImageManager()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)

        for i in 0..<result.count {
            let asset = result.object(at: i)

            // Now generate thumbnails for the assets
            imageManager.requestImage(
                for: asset,
                targetSize: ...,
                contentMode: .aspectFill,
                options: requestOptions,
                resultHandler: { (image, error) in
                    if let photo = image {
                        self.photos.append(
                            PhotoLibraryAsset.init(
                                asset.mediaType == .video ? "Video" : "Photo",
                                thumbnail: image!
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        ...

        let photo = photos[indexPath.row]
        if photo.assetType == "Video" {
            // Add a "Video" label to the bottom-right corner of the cell
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

**Question**

Some photos also have "Video" label in its bottom-right corner, why? Also, after closing the screen and re-opening it, some of the photos that had "Video" labels now don't have it any more, however, some that didn't now do. How should I go about this?

**Update**

This is what the picker looks like, of all the photos that are tagged "Video", in fact, only 1 of them really is a video:

[image]

Comment: are you creating and adding the `UILabel` in the `cellForRowAt:` delegate itself?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Typically this is because you've forgotten that cells are reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are creating and adding the `UILabel` in the `cellForRowAt:`. Because the cells will be reused and so the video label will appear randomly in those cells. I suggest adding the label from storyboard or XIB only. Or you can create and add the label in `awakeFromNib` also But then you will have to implement `prepareForReuse` and hide the label there.